# Apple pay Works on simulator but getting error in real device: not supported on this device

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, applepay

I created the merchant, generated the certificates and did configuration about it. the Apple Pay Button visible in simulator but not visible in real device. I added testing cards in apple Wallet app with setting US region in device.

I used the @stripe/stripe-react-native for Stripe react-native UI SDK.

While I checking with real device it given **"Apple pay is not supported on this device"**. I tried with iPhone 6s and iPhone 13.

Comment: Please note you cannot use Stripe test cards with Apple Pay. You'll need to have real card data in your wallet to process payments in test mode. Stripe will substitute the real data for a test token. This is highlighted [here](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay?platform=react-native#testing-apple-pay).

Comment: Thanks!! Jonathan I tested with real card as well.

Comment: I would recommend [contacting Stripe](https://support.stripe.com/contact) for some support!

Comment: facing the same issue here. Were you able to get it working?

Comment: Diego, Still Not found any solution for that.

Comment: Kind of a side question, but did you add the cards directly in the simulator wallet app? When I open the wallet app, there's not even a way for me to add a card at all. It just has a little modal about getting an app to keep track of tickets, boarding passes, etc. Maybe I also have to add the cards on a real device? Which would be annoying because I have an android.

Comment: On a real device I had to enable apple cash in settings to get it to work. Not sure why.